# UWP VS2015 .Net 4.61 Add Web Reference Button Missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  I have scoured the web trying to find an answer. I am writing a UWP app that will be deployed to the Xbox platform.  I need to access a web service written in .Net 2.0.  In earlier versions of .Net / Visual Studio the Add Web Reference Button was hidden in a panel accessed through ->Add Service Reference ->Advanced ->Add Web Reference.  With latest build of VS2015 the Add Web Reference Button is missing.  Did this completely go away or is it hidden even deeper in the environment somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

XML Web Services, also known as ASMX services, were the predecessor of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). You can access Web Services by adding a service reference just as you would for any other WCF service.

> A service reference enables a project to access one or more Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) services. Use the **Add Service Reference** dialog box to search for WCF services in the current solution, locally, on a local area network, or on the Internet.

For more info, please [How to: Add, Update, or Remove a Service Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I understand this.  I was specifically asking however if the Add "Web" Service button was enabled anywhere within the environment.  I have a very old asmx service that I want to reuse and Add Web Service automatically built all of the scaffolding for asmx enabling just calling the service and method in code.  Add Service Reference creates the SOAP interfaces but requires building the SOAP Headers and Body which is more work and complexity.

Comment: @slrbatman I'm not sure what your asmx service is. I tested with the service [here](http://www.webservicex.net/New/Home/ServiceDetail/10). Using `http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL` as **Address** and give a **Namespace** like `CurrencyConvertor`. Then I can use this service like `CurrencyConvertor.CurrencyConvertorSoapClient convertor = new CurrencyConvertor.CurrencyConvertorSoapClient();
            var conversionRate = await convertor.ConversionRateAsync(CurrencyConvertor.Currency.GBP, CurrencyConvertor.Currency.USD);`. You can have a try.